# PC (Server) , Android (Client) Bluetooth Library Bluecove

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, bluecove

I was trying to use Bluecove library on my Windows 7 Professional PC , using a usb bluetooth radio/ dongle attached to the PC. The bluetooth dongle used BlueSoliel version 6 . The bluecove documentation suggests to use BlueSoleil version 1.6.0, 2.3 or 3.2.2.8. Version 5.0.5 +  are not supported. And I cannot install 2.3 or other on my Windows 7 Professional . Is there any other bluetooth library open source and free for use.

Basically what i want is to use my PC as a server and I want my Android Mobile as a client that connects to my PC. I am working on a Simulator. Please suggest any pointers in this direction. I would be thankful :) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BlueCove docs are described [the supported stacks](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/wiki/stacks) you should consult it. One of the stacks supported on Windows it is as you said BlueSoleil, but also they support Microsoft BT stack and Broadcom(Widcomm). You should try install Microsoft BT stack, I think it will solve your problems.